# Python tkinter: Add button to menu bar

Tags: python, user-interface, menu, tkinter

I am trying to add a button to the far right of the menubar in my program. But it isn't working for me. When I connect it to 'root' it appears below it; when I attach it to 'menubar' or 'filemenu' it doesn't show up at all. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)

# set up button
btn1 = Button(root, text='x')
btn1.pack(side='right', anchor='n', padx=0, pady=0)

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)

# add commands to menu
filemenu.add_command(label="New File")
filemenu.add_command(label="Open")
filemenu.add_command(label="Save")
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)    

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do what you want. The menubar is a special, native control that doesn't support the ability to add random buttons to it.

You can use `add_command` on the menubar itself rather than a submenu, but I think your users would be surprised at this. People generally expect to get a menu when they click on something on the menubar.

Comment: Oh.. hm.. Well I have a bunch of tabs and I am trying to figure out what would be the best way to close each one individually out would be. I could put a 'X' on the tab I guess but I am not sure how to.

Comment: @user2638731: how about adding a "Tabs" menu to the menubar, and under that have "Delete current tab"?

Comment: I am just wondering, if I use the 'add_command' is there some way I can make it show up on the very right?

Comment: @user2638731: no, there is not.